# Including a third party python package in Django on app-engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a django app running on appengine and it works fine. Now I want to extend it to use a third party python package - googleanalytics. No matter where I put this package django complaints about not finding it (Error was: No module named googleanalytics).

My dir structure is as follows-

app.yaml
myproject
  -settings.py
  -manage.py
  -templates
  -googleanalytics
  -urls.py
  -myapp
    -views.py (uses googleanalytics package)

Per some suggestions here I also tried using -
    sys.path.insert(0, ROOT_PATH) 
I also tried some other paths with this but nothing seems to work. I installed the package and even that does not work.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.path.insert (0, os.path.abspath (
  os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), 'googleanalytics')))
```

Comment: Sahid - That did not work. Its almost like something resetting the path after this.

Comment: I decided to use google app engine helper and that worked like a charm! It was simple to use and I was up and running in 20 minutes. Highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use google app engine helper and that worked like a charm! It was simple to use and I was up and running in 20 minutes. Highly recommend it.